# Stop an absolute positioned div to move within relative parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have two `divs` inside a container. One is `absolutely` positioned and is on the top. The second `div` is the bottom of their container. They are both inside a container that is has `position: relative`. If the user scrolls **horizontally not vertically** on the bottom `div`, the absolutely positioned `div` will also scroll. The problem is that since it is positioned absolutely, the entire `div` will move when the bottom is scrolled.

Is there a way to prevent this? I just want to div to remain in place no matter what.

Here is a JSFiddle example. I can't just change the `position: relative` attribute of the container because in my case, it would mess up everything else in the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/2m16rtjp/6/

To see a desired set of results (I'm talking about how it is viewed when scrolling horizontally), replace `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` for `.titleSection-right`. I need to have the `div` positioned absolutely for a plugin to work.

Comment: I'm not at all certain what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like `position: fixed` is what you're looking for. Also, try to provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](minimal, complete and verifyable example) within your post, instead of linking external pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my example covers the problem enough to understand it. I've been using JSFiddle for a while and see it all over SO. It's kind of ironic how your link is broken. @TheThirdMan

Comment: If you could post an image explaining your regions and how they relate, their might be a better way to solve the markup structure

Comment: Are you looking for pure css solution or js will work for you too?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Any solutions are good.

Comment: @Jimenemex: It's ironic alright, but nevertheless, a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) within your post is helpful in the future, when external links might have already vanished, plus people who jsfiddle won't work for (such as myself) will be able to look at it. One could also say it's good will to follow the guidelines of a page you're hoping to provide answers to your problems, instead of observing what the majority does (which likely stems from days where SO didn't have the snippet functionality anyhow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided new fiddle with simple markup, as yours is not clear enough, hope this help,
The idea is very simple, on `rightSide` scroll, we can change `left` of `titleSection-right`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative; 
    width 500px; 
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.box1 {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color:red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box1 > div{
    width: 2000px; 
    height: 200px;
}
.box1 + div{
    width: 2000px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function(){
  $('.box1').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qxxvuu41/)

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for, is there any way to prevent it from shaking when scrolling? (I understand why it's doing it, just looks unprofessional)

Comment: You're looking for something that is not possible with pure CSS, the way that I mentioned is correct way, but maybe you need to review your `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:fixed` instead of `postion:absolute`

```
.titleSection-right {
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `position: fixed`. I need to have it `position: absolute` because a plugin requires it to work.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your `script`

```
$(".rightSide").scroll(function() {
    if ($(".rightSide").scrollLeft() > 0)
    {
        $(".titleSection-right").css( "position", "fixed" );
    } else {
        $(".titleSection-right").css( "position", "absolute" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution involves scrolling vertically, I was talking about scrolling horizontally.

Comment: try this script now it will work  horizontally with the `rightSide div`